# Android google map can't parse feature type road.local.trail

Tags: android, google-maps

I've created map style json for dark mode using map style wizard. I edited road.local.trail visibility. I exported that in android studio. As a result the app showed light mode map style instead of night mode style. When I deleted item with

```
"featureType": "road.local.trail",
```

all worked fine again.

What should I do to apply changes for this feature type?

I used the latest version of the sdk at this moment

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
```

I noticed that there is legacy style editor wizard, it hasn't road.local.trail feature type to edit. It has only road.local without any child.

Comment: I added initialization with LATEST renderer in App onCreate() lifecycle method, but it doesn't work anyway

MapsInitializer.initialize(this, MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST, null);

Comment: In log I see this error: InvalidStyleException: Unknown feature type: road.local.trail

Comment: Where in the documentation have you seen this `featureType`?

Comment: @Yrll I saw it in generated JSON file from map style editor wizard. But yes, in the official page about map styling I didn't see this feature type